# Facebook API: Uploading photo to the wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a photo to my page's wall (and am doing so successfully) but not the way I'd like to.

Here's how I'd like the photo to show up: http://screencast.com/t/wnRFBh1xlf

However, here's how it actually shows up: http://screencast.com/t/4WblA7s8fyE

Here's the code I'm using with cURL to upload the photo (or rather, link to it)

```
$img_url = "url";
$page_id = "XXXXX";
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id/feed";
$fields = array(
                        'access_token'=>urlencode("XXXXXXX"),
                        'message'=>urlencode("Far Cry 3!"),
                        'picture'=>$img_url
                );
```

So, from what I can tell, I should be able to store the image on my server and post the source of the image over, but I just get an error when I do that.

Here's that code and error...

"{"error":{"message":"(#100) source URL is not properly formatted","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}"

```
$img_url = 'url';
$img = 'temp_image.jpg';
$contents = file_get_contents($img_url);
file_put_contents($img, $contents);
$path = realpath($img);
//echo $path;

//set POST variables
$page_id = "XXXXXX";
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id/feed";
$fields = array(
                        'access_token'=>urlencode("XXXXXXX"),
                        'message'=>urlencode("Far Cry 3!"),
                        'source'=>"@".$path
                );
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, and have been searching all night for it - with no luck.

Hopefully somebody can give me a clue as to what I should actually be doing.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show a `$img_url` sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're posting to the `/feed` connection there, if you want the larger image, you need to actually upload the photo to one of the user's photo albums  (i.e the `/photos` connection)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't realize that. When manually doing this I've always just posted pictures straight to the wall. That helps a lot. I'll let you know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Add `?type=large` (or one of: small, normal or square) at the end of url to send a large photo

Comment: Gabriel - how would that work? he's uploading images, not retrieving them from the API

Comment: Igy, so I **should** be able to post to pageid/photos with the same data (the real path)? Is that correct?

Comment: Hi, posting on facebook user's wall it is possible but is it any way to post on user's wall who have not made the facebook app. i am trying to upload photo and text using publish_actions. photo and text are uploaded only by me because i have created app but is it possible to post on user's wall who have not made facebook app so please tell me ASAP.